# multiple udp socket in a single program slows down my program

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, udp

i am getting data from multiple sensors to my main.py through udp socket but the problem here is that sometimes it just slows down the whole program or freezes for few seconds. I am running it on jetson nano with ubuntu 18.04. Is there a better way of doing it?

my code reads as follows:

```
while True:
        stdoutdata = subprocess.getoutput("hcitool con")
        try:
            while True:
                data, addr = uv_sock.recvfrom(1024, socket.MSG_DONTWAIT)

        except:
            pass
            # print("did not recieve data from controls")

        try:
            bluetooth_controls = data.decode()
            bluetooth_controls = ast.literal_eval(bluetooth_controls)   
            print("bluetooth_controls:", bluetooth_controls)         
        
        except:
            pass

        try:
            while True:
                data, fromAddr = wall_sock.recvfrom(1024, socket.MSG_DONTWAIT)
                rpmRs, rpmLs = data.decode().split("and")

        except:
            rpmRs, rpmLs = rpmRs, rpmLs
            # print('except1')

        # receive imu(gyro) data 
        try:
            while True:
                pkt, fromAddr = imu_sock.recvfrom(128, socket.MSG_DONTWAIT)
                # print("got packet")
        except:
            pkt = pkt
        
        try:
            newestData = None
            keepReceiving = True
            while keepReceiving:
                try:
                    data = lidar_data_sock.recv(4096, socket.MSG_DONTWAIT)
                    if data:
                        newestData = data
                except socket.error as why:
                    if why.args[0] == 11:
                        keepReceiving = False
                    else:
                        raise why
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: You should use `select` to wait efficiently on one or more sockets.

Comment: @rveerd do you have any examples?

Comment: Not in Python, no. Googling for "python socket select" gives [this example](https://steelkiwi.com/blog/working-tcp-sockets/) which appears to be a good introduction.